# Projective variety containing hyperplane at infinity

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $V$ be a projective variety containing the hyperplane at infinity $H_{\infty}$. Why does it follow then that $V = \mathbb{P}^n$ or $V = H_{\infty}?$
Obviously $I(H_{\infty} )= (X_{n+1})$, but I don't see why a point $(x_1: \dots : x_n : 1) \in V$ implies all points in $\in V$.

**Update**
Thinking about irreducibility more properly (which I assume for a variety) I see an even simpler argument.
Assume there would be a $V$ s.t. $H_{\infty} \subsetneq V \subsetneq \mathbb{P}^n$. So choose an $0 \ne F \in I(V)$. Since $I(H_{\infty}) = (X_{n+1})$, $F = X^{r}_{n+1}G$, where $r$ is the highest power of $X_{n+1}$ which divides $F$. Since $V$ is irreducible subsequently applying the prime ideal condition in $I(V)$ implies $G \in I(V)$, as $X_{n+1} \notin I(V)$. But this is a contradiction as there obviously is a point $P \in H_{\infty}$, where $G(P) \ne 0$.

Comment: A nicer way to reach your conclusion is that $G \in I(V) \subset (X_{n+1})$, but $X_{n+1} \nmid G$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends on your definition for a variety. If you require it to be *irreducible*, the answer is *yes* (otherwise it’s no, since you can just consider the reunion of two hyperplanes, one of which is the hyperplane at infinity).

So assume that $V \subset \mathbb{P}^n$ is irreducible and contains a hyperplane at infinity. Then $V \supset H_{\infty} \cong \mathbb{P}^{n-1}$, so the dimension (the Krull dimension for topological space, ie the length of a maximal chain of irreducible closed subspaces) of $V$ is at least that of $\mathbb{P}^{n-1}$ which is $n-1$ (that fact is *not* obvious though). But $V \subset \mathbb{P}^n$ so that $V$ has dimension at most $n$ for the same reason.

Now, here’s the thing about Krull dimension: if $V \subset W$ is a closed subset of a topological space and if $V,W$ are irreducible with the same finite dimension, then $V=W$. You can check that by assuming $V \neq W$ and consider a chain of maximal length in $V$, and appending $W$ at its end – it becomes too long for $W$.

So if $V$ has dimension $n-1$, you apply the previous paragraph to $H_{\infty} \subset V$, and otherwise to $V \subset \mathbb{P}^n$.